# Cannot plot above bar on chart

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot a triangle when a given signal occurs:

```
var r1 = 5
var r2 = 10

signal = highest(r1) >= highest(r2) and lowest(r1) <= lowest(r2)
plotshape(signal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green)
```

It does plot, but not on the chart itself:

[image]

How can I plot shapes `abovebar`?

Answer (score 0):

Your indicator needs to be on the chart rather than in a separate pane. Use `overlay = true` in your [`study()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_study) declaration statement, and when you make the change, re-add your indicator to the chart to implement the change.